# Determine if Qt App has a UI

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm working on a large project that uses Qt. The application has the option of running both in GUI or batch modes, and I don't have access to that info where I am at.

But, I do have access to the QApp. Is there a way to know through Qt if an UI exists or has been initialized?

Comment: What do you need from QApp? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QApplication` has a [`topLevelWidgets()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets) function that returns a list of top-level widgets. You could check if that list is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [QCoreApplication](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html) instead of [QApplication](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html), for the batch mode? You're not supposed to use QApplication for non-GUI applications.

If you do it this way, the qApp should either return a pointer to a QCoreApplication (non-GUI), or QApplication (GUI), which you can check at runtime (if you need to) with a dynamic_cast.

Comment: QCoreApplication is actually used ion both cases. I don't really have a choice of using what is already there, as I am just working on a plugin.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a QApplication objects needs to be instantiated in order to create a GUI object. Are you sure that it uses QCoreApplication in both cases?

Comment: To do the `dynamic_cast` trick, you would need to pull in the header file with the definition of `QApplication` and its various dependencies.  *(Because you're testing to see if the cast to a `QApplication` from a `QCoreApplication` fails, not vice versa.)*  This would not be desirable if the person was developing a `QCoreApplication`, as the point was to not include the Gui parts in the build...

Answer (score 0):

Depening on the operating system, you can look at environment variables to determine if showing a gui is even possible. In my Linux setup, if the environment variable `DISPLAY` is set, a desktop environment is available. If I log in through ssh or boot in headless mode, the variable is not set.

This is not the optimal solution for David's answer, but it has the advantage of working independently of the `QApp` object. For example, in my case it had to be determined *before* the app was initialized.

```cpp
bool guiCanBeShown(void)
{
    return !qgetenv("DISPLAY").isEmpty();
}
```